# Capturing 'shown' event from bootstrap tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have some 'static' HTML on my page:

```
<div id="DIVISIONS">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="DIVISIONTABS">
        @* <li> nodes will be injected here by javascript *@
    </ul>
    <div class="tab-content" id="DIVISIONTABPANES">
        @* <div class="tab-pane"> nodes will be injected here by javascript *@
    </div>
</div>
```

On page load, I create a tab 'framework', i.e. create the bootstrap tabs and tab content containers.

I trigger the process with:

```
$(window).bind("load", prepareDivisionTabs);
```

And "prepareDivisionTabs" does this:

```
function prepareDivisionTabs() {
    // Retrieve basic data for creating tabs
    $.ajax({
        url: "@Url.Action("GetDivisionDataJson", "League")",
        cache: false
    }).done(function (data) {
        var $tabs = $('#DIVISIONTABS').empty();
        var $panes = $('#DIVISIONTABPANES').empty();
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            var d = data[i];
            $tabs.append("<li><a href=\"#TABPANE" + d.DivisionId + "\" data-toggle=\"tab\">" + NMWhtmlEncode(d.Name) + "</a></li>");
            $panes.append("<div id=\"TABPANE" + d.DivisionId + "\" class=\"tab-pane\"></div>")
        }
        renderDivisionTabPaneContents(data);
    }).fail(function (err) {
        alert("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    });
}
```

For info, the "renderDivisionTabPaneContents" in the above does this:

```
function renderDivisionTabPaneContents(data) {
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var d = data[i];
        renderDivisionTabPaneContent(d.DivisionId);
    }
}

function renderDivisionTabPaneContent(id) {
    var $tabPane = $('#TABPANE' + id);
    $tabPane.addClass("loader")
    $.ajax({
        url: "/League/GetDivisionPartialView?divisionId=" + id,
        cache: false
    }).done(function (html) {
        $tabPane.html(html);
    }).fail(function (err) {
        alert("AJAX error in request: " + JSON.stringify(err, null, 2));
    }).always(function () {
        $tabPane.removeClass("loader")
    });
}
```

**All good so far.**  My page loads, my tab contents are rendered, and when I click the different tabs, the relevant content is shown.

Now, rather than loading all content at the start, I want to load tab content just-in-time by using the 'shown' event of the tabs.  To test this, I've wanted to just make sure I could get a javascript alert when the tab was shown.  So, I create the following to trigger the attachment of tab shown events:

```
$(function () {
    attachTabShownEvents();
})
```

which calls:

```
function attachTabShownEvents() {
    $(document).on('shown', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
        alert('TAB CHANGED');
    })
}
```

I'd therefore expect so see the "TAB CHANGED" alert after the change of tab.  But ... I see no alerts.

Could anybody help me out here?

Comment: Have you tried replacing `$(window).bind("load", prepareDivisionTabs);` with `$(prepareDivisionTabs);`?

Comment: I'll give it a go and report back, but that part of the process seems fine at the moment as the tabs created during "prepareDivisionTabs" are working correctly.  It's just the subsequent event handler that I try to add that is not working.  UPDATE: Just made the suggested change and the behaviour is identical (i.e. tabs work in terms of screen behaviour, but still do not fire the 'shown' event).

Comment: Oh, and I believe the event bind should be `shown.bs.tab`, not `shown`

Comment: "shown.bs.tab" cracked it!  Many thanks 'windy'.

Answer (score 97, accepted):

The correct event binding for tab change is `shown.bs.tab`.

```
$(document).on('shown.bs.tab', 'a[data-toggle="tab"]', function (e) {
    alert('TAB CHANGED');
})
```

**Update 11-01-2020 --- Bootstrap 4.5**

This is still the correct answer however, this is a bit of additional helpful information found all the way at the bottom of the official bootstrap docs page at: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/components/navs/#tabs

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  e.target // newly activated tab
  e.relatedTarget // previous active tab
})
```

You can determine which tab has been selected each time the code fires with `e.target`.

If you have unique IDs on your elements then you could do something like the following so code only runs when the appropriate tab is clicked.

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  switch (e.target.id){
      case "mainTab":{
           doMainTabStuff();
           break;
      }
      case "configTab":{
           doConfigTabStuff();
           break;
      }
  }
})
```

Comment: This is the way to do it... Ignore most of the other suggestions on SO they don't work ;)

Comment: How would you adapt this to work for one specific tab?

Comment: @Richard `$(selector).on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) { alert('TAB CHANGED'); })`

Comment: $(selector).on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) { alert('TAB CHANGED'); }) , This one is not working for me

Comment: $(selector) is the parent div of the ul element

Answer (score 4):

```
<a data-toggle="tab" href="#some_special_tab_anchor">

<div id="some_special_tab_anchor" class="tab-pane fade">
    special tab content
</div>

            $( 'a[data-toggle="tab"]' ).on( 'shown.bs.tab', function( evt ) {

                var anchor = $( evt.target ).attr( 'href' );
                alert("TAB SHOWN = "+anchor);

                // take action based on what tab was shown
               if(anchor === "some_special_tab_anchor"){
                  // do my special thing :)
               }

            });
```

Comment: Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 0):

Use my Nuget package for lazyloading bootstrap tabs here, its very simple, 
just add "lazyload" class to the "ul" element of bootstrap tabs, then add "data-url" equal to url to load to the any tabs anchor element (a). thats it.

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MT.BootstrapTabsLazyLoader.js/

Answer (score 0):

'show' and 'shown' events didn't work for me. My solution is not exactly specifically OP's situation, but the general concepts are there.

I had the same issue with bootstrap forcing its own onclick events 
on tabs (menu buttons and content panels). I wanted to lazy load stuff into a panel depending on what menu button was clicked, and some buttons show a panel on the current page, others were to load a page into an iframe.

At first, I stuffed data into a hidden form field tag, which was the same issue. The trick is to detect some sort of change and act on that. I solved the problem by forcing a change and using an alternate event listening on the buttons without having to touch bootstrap.

1) stash iframe target in button as data attribute:

```
$('#btn_for_iframe').attr('data-url',iframeurl);
```

2) bind alternate event onto fire off thingy,
and inside, swap out the iframe source

```
$('#btn_for_iframe').on('mouseup',function(){
   console.log(this+' was activated');
   $('#iframe').attr('src',$('#btn_for_iframe').attr('data-url'));
});
```

3) force 'change' event on panel shows, then load iframe src

```
$('#iframe_panel_wrapper').show().trigger('change');
```

or you can put the change trigger in the mouseup above.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".nav-tabs a").click(function(){
        $(this).tab('show');
    });
    $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function(event){
        alert('tab shown');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

vanilla js (Bootstrap 5.3)

```
myTabBtn.addEventListener('shown.bs.tab', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
});
```